# determine the power series 1/P(x) for a power series P(x)

Tags: calculus, analysis

We have a power series $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n(n+1)x^n$ and now have to determine the power series $\frac{1}{P(x)}$. I am at a total loss here, maybe one of you can help.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? What do you usually do with this kind of problem? You will get more help if you show us what you tried.

Comment: so far i wrote down the explicit representation of P(x) and tried to form $\frac{1}{a_n}$ so that i could then form a summation. But that hasnt helped and i dont think that is the right approach so i tried googling and found this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic  which leads me to believe that i somehow have to do it recursively, but since this is the first time trying to solve a problem like this im just not sure if i am even on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(x) &= 1\cdot1  - 2\cdot2x + 4\cdot3x^2 - 8\cdot4x^3  + \cdots\\
\implies 2xP(x) &= \phantom{1 . 1}  +2\cdot1x - 4\cdot2x^2 + 8\cdot3x^3  + \cdots
\end{align}

Adding the above equations gives us
$$(1+2x)P(x) = 1 - 2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3 + \cdots$$
The RHS above is an infinite geometric series with common ratio $-2x$ and thus, we get
$$(1+2x)P(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+2x}.$$

Rearranging gives us $$\dfrac{1}{P(x)} = (1+2x)^2,$$
the power series of which, I leave to the daring reader to calculate.